# Use variables from +(void)initialize in other functions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization, scope

So I have the following `initialize` method :

```
+(void)initialize 
{
    static BOOL init = NO 
    if init == NO
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = @{NSFontAttributeName......};
            init = YES;
        }
}
```

Now, I have a method say - `drawer` which requires `dict`

```
-(void) drawer:(CGRect)rect 
{
    [self.string drawInRect:CGRect........... withAttributes:dict];
}
```

When I call the `dict` in `drawer`, Xcode says - "Use of undeclared identifier `dict`. Why does this happen? Can someone help me out here? How do I get this method to access `dict`?

Comment: What's the point of the `init` variable? `initialize` is only called once per class.

Comment: @rmaddy: I have actually burned myself with that assumption before. If your class is involved in key-value observing, `+initialize` can actually be called twice: once in your class (for example, `VSGame`), and a second time in the private KVO class (`NSKVONotifying_VSGame`). So, depending on what you're doing in that method, you may want to take those kind of precautions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, `dict` in `+(void)initialize` is local variable of that function. Therefore, in `-(void)drawer:` you can't access `dict` since it isn't in same scope.

If you want to use `dict` as global variable accessible anywhere, Declare it out of the function scope.

Comment: Best to declare it as a file-scoped variable, using `static`, rather than global.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes. That's my favorite way to avoid clashes of symbols.